# BAZEL + bash: execute bash/python script to do code generation and use them in bazel system

Tags: bash, bazel, bazel-rules

I am new to Bazel. I have a project which is built with Bazel.
But some of the source files are pre-codegened and then compile them with Bazel.
Now I can run the bash script standalone and run the bazel command:

```
.
|-- project
|   |-- BUILD (will depend on temp_output:codegen)
|   |-- scripts
|   |   |-- codegen.sh (read config.yaml and generate codegen.cpp/hpp and a BUILD.bazel)
|   |-- config
|   |   |-- config.yaml
|   |-- temp_output
|   |   |-- codegen.cpp (not existed before running codegen.sh)
|   |   |-- codegen.hpp (not existed before running codegen.sh)
|   |   |-- BAZEL.build (not existed before running codegen.sh)
|-- WORKSPACE



$ ./scripts/codegen.sh
$ bazel build :project
```

What are done in the codegen.sh:

1. Read the config.yaml where the contains some other WORKSPACE path and name.
2. Query the targets in that WORKSPACE.
3. Create cpp/hpp files to include some headers files.
4. Create a new BUILD file, adding the depends on those targets.

My goal is to embed the bash script in the bazel system. I tried with rule + action.run. But the failures are for:

1. sandbox directory is not readable nor writable.
2. input files cannot be found in sandbox.

Is there a fancy way to do this? Or any examples I can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is with [genrule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#genrule). Something like this in `project/BUILD`:

```py
genrule(
    name = "run_codegen",
    srcs = [
        "codegen.sh",
        "config.yaml",
    ],
    outs = [
        "codegen.cpp",
        "codegen.hpp",
    ],
    cmd = "$(location codegen.sh) --config $(location config.yaml) --cpp $(location codegen.cpp) --hpp $(location codegen.hpp)",
)

cc_library(
    name = "codegen",
    hdrs = [ "codegen.hpp" ],
    srcs = [ "codegen.cpp" ],
)
```

Some things to note:

- Using `$(location)` to get the paths for the input and output files. If the script uses relative paths, I'd modify it to take the paths as arguments, or write a wrapper script that creates a temporary directory and moves things to/from there based on flags. The only other reliable way to create paths is with ["make" variables](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/make-variables.html), but those are generally harder to work with and more brittle with respect to modifications to the genrule.
- Not generating a `BUILD` file. You can only do this from a [repository rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/repository_rules.html), and it gets significantly more complicated. I don't think you need to for this use case, just write the rule in `project/BUILD`.

If you want to embed this in a rule instead of using genrule for some reason, make sure you're using [File.path](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/File.html#path) to get all the paths to embed in the command. That's the equivalent of `$(location)`. It's hard to be more specific about why your rule doesn't work without seeing a copy of it.

Comment: Hi @Brian

Thanks for your help.
About the BUILD file, I have to create a new BUILD file. The content about the BUILD file is also codegen as well.

Comment: What parts of the BUILD file need to be generated? Depending on what parts need to change, there are ways to use custom rules instead.

Comment: Hi @Brian Silverman
I tried the genrule. But failed.


cc_library(
    name = "codegen",
    data = [":run_codegen"],
)

genrule(
    name = "run_codegen",
    srcs = [
        "codegen_test.sh",
    ],
    outs = [
        "tmp_output.cpp",
    ],
    cmd = "$(location codegen_test.sh) $(location tmp_output.cpp)",
)

I need to use codegen_test.sh to generate the tmp_output.cpp but it reported "bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/tmp_output.cpp: No such file or directory".

Comment: Putting it in cc_library.data means the files in that rule can load the .cpp file at runtime, which is unusual. I think you want it in cc_library.srcs instead.

Is codegen_test.sh changing to a different directory before trying to use that relative path maybe?

Comment: Hi

Yes. It is because I changed to another path. 

Another question is that, during the codegen, I will call "cd $AnotherWORKSPACE; bazel query xxxx". And then I will do string split and figure out the codegen content. 

It seems I cannot call "bazel query" again in the script.

Comment: Looks like I don't have permission to run "bazel query" in the script.

Comment: Hi @Brian Silverman

I found my issues can be solved by just adding one tags = "local".